# Jetty altering/inserting different "Expires" http header

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a standalone jetty application. Requests to Jetty are coming through with an expires header in the past:

```
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Which is a different expires header than the one I am setting. I cant work out why this is occurring? I am setting expires (along with other headers) as follows, inside a servlet filter:

```
public class AuthorisationFilter implements Filter {

public void init (FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    expires = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    expires.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // ....
    if(url.endsWith(".eot") || url.endsWith(".ttf") || url.endsWith(".woff")) {
        response.setHeader("Expires", expires.format(new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*86400))));
    } else if(url.endsWith(".css") || url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".gif") || url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".ico")) {
        response.setHeader("Expires", expires.format(new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*500))));
    } else {
        response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 1:00:00 GMT");
    }

chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I am registering the servlet filter as follows:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", false, false);

FilterHolder f = new FilterHolder(new UrlFilter(jee));
context.addFilter(f, "/*", null);
f = new FilterHolder(new AuthorisationFilter(jee);
context.addFilter(f, "/*", null);
```

Comment: I have tried various ways of setting the Expires header, nothing I do seems to make it come out in the right format.

Comment: Two awesome answers, who answered first? (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general advice.

1. Set it before you access [HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) or [HttpServletResponse.getWriter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29)
2. When setting a date header, like Expires, use [HttpServletResponse.setDateHeader(String name, long date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setDateHeader%28java.lang.String,%20long%29)

Comment: This one appears on top, so this one was first?

Answer (score 2):

You might try to use the `setDateHeader()` method instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setDateHeader(java.lang.String,%20long)